# Estimate/Print csv COPY status to postgresql table

Tags: postgresql, copy, psql

I want to get an idea of how long it will take to copy a csv to a postgresql table. Is there a way to print the rows copied in a reasonable fashion or is there another way to somehow display the progress of the copy?

Perhaps there is a verbose setting or I should use --echo or -qecho

I am using:

`psql -U postgres -d nyc_data -h localhost -c "\COPY rides FROM nyc_data_rides.csv CSV"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such thing unfortunately.

One idea would be to divide the input into chunks of 1000 or 10000 lines, which you then import one after the other. That wouldn't slow processing considerably, and you can quickly get an estimate how long the whole import is going to take.

Answer (score 7):

In Postgres 14, it's now possible to query the status of an active `COPY` via the internal `pg_stat_progress_copy` view.

e.g. to watch progress in terms of both bytes and lines processed:

```sql
select * from pg_stat_progress_copy \watch 1
```

Refs:

- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/progress-reporting.html#COPY-PROGRESS-REPORTING
- https://www.depesz.com/2021/01/12/waiting-for-postgresql-14-report-progress-of-copy-commands/

Answer (score 3):

use pv tool

```
pv /tmp/some_table.csv | sudo -u postgres psql -d some_db -c "copy some_table from stdin delimiter ',' null '';"
```

and as a result, it will show

```
1.42GiB 0:11:42 [2.06MiB/s] [===================================================================================================================================================================>] 100%
```

Answer (score 0):

As Laurenz Albe said, there's no way to measure how many time remaining to conclude the entire process. But one thing that I did today to take a good approximation was:

- Start the "Monitor System" in my Linux
- In this application there's a counter that how many data was uploaded since I started this application
- Using the size of the file that I was uploading I made a good prediction about how many data was left to send to the server.